# How to get OnetoMany results with nested JSON in JPA

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have 2 POJO as below:

**UserDto**

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "c_um_npk_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_sequence", sequenceName = "t_user_master_c_um_npk_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "c_um_vnm_username", nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @JsonManagedReference("user-role")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userDto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<RoleDto> roleDtos;

/* other fields are omitted for simplicity */
```

**RoleDto**

```
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "role_sequence", sequenceName = "t_user_roles_c_ur_npk_role_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "role_sequence")
    @Column(name = "c_ur_npk_role_id", nullable = false)
    private Long Id;
    @JsonBackReference("user-role")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_ur_nfk_user_id")
    private UserDto userDto;
    @Column(name = "c_ur_vnm_role")
    String role;
```

/** getter setter omitted **/

Now, I tried with JPA

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT ud.id,ud.username,roles.role from UserDto ud JOIN ud.roleDtos roles WHERE ud.username = :username")
                .setParameter("username", userName).getResultList();
```

Here I need SingleResult with below expected result

```
{
   id : 1,
   username : abc123,
   roleDtos :[
      {
         role : 'SUPER_ADMIN'
      },{
         role : 'SUPPORT_PERSON'
      }
   ]
}
```

but I am not getting nested object with JPA results, and getting many rows in DB like

```
1. id : 1, 
   username : abc123
   role : SUPER_ADMIN

2. id : 1,
   username : abc123
   role : SUPPORT_PERSON
```

Am i missed anything with JPA? Please help me thanks in Advance.

Comment: JPA does not create JSON. JPA persists objects to a database, and retrieves them ... as Java objects. You then have to use a JSON serialiser to create the JSON.

Comment: is there any link from where I can take reference?

Comment: reference of what? You need to DEFINE where the problem lies ... in getting the java objects out of the database, or in converting to JSON. Internet search provides all the references you should need

Comment: FetchMode Join can help you.`@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID", nullable = false)
public Stock getStock() {
    return this.stock;
}`